# Table Value Function vs Scalar Value Function Which one has Better Performance vise in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, function

According to my searching Table Value Function in SQL has batter performance as compare to Scalar value function. But any one can you please tell me about that which one has better performance.

**Note: I have not concern that i need to return single or multiple values, i'm just asking about performance wise which one is better.**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think the main driver in choosing one over the other is ... whether you need to return a single value or a table.  Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: I have not concern that i need to return single or multiple values, i'm just asking about performance wise which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the function to return a single value, then you would use a scalar function.

Obviously, any scalar function can be converted to a table-valued function that returns one row and one column.  I do not see any utility in that.

As for the additional overhead of converting a scalar-valued function to such a table-valued function.  I've never checked.  It doesn't seem particularly useful.  I would speculate that the overhead for a user-defined function is so big anyway that the additional overhead of returning the value as a table would be rather small compared to the overall overhead.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I have not concern that i need to return single or multiple values, i'm just asking about performance wise which one is better.

Comment: @TechleadzTeam . . . They do different things, so it is like comparing the performance of `group by` versus `join`.